# htaccess redirect rule for Amazon CloudFront IPs

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, amazon-cloudfront

I have setup a CDN plugin on a joomla website using CloudFront.

All seems to be working fine, except all request from CloudFront are redirected to the www version of the website domain.
It seems this is due to the non-www -> www redirec rule.

I have calculated the IP range used by CloudFront as per this post:
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ann.jspa?annID=910

And I have obtained the following IP ranges:

HostMin: 54.239.128.1
HostMax: 54.239.191.254

HostMin: 54.240.128.1
HostMax: 54.240.191.254

HostMin: 204.246.168.1
HostMax: 204.246.171.254

HostMin: 204.246.174.1
HostMax: 204.246.175.254

HostMin: 204.246.176.1
HostMax: 204.246.191.254

HostMin: 205.251.192.1
HostMax: 205.251.223.254

HostMin: 205.251.249.1
HostMax: 205.251.249.254

HostMin: 205.251.250.1
HostMax: 205.251.251.254

HostMin: 205.251.252.1
HostMax: 205.251.253.254

HostMin: 205.251.254.1
HostMax: 205.251.254.254

HostMin: 216.137.32.1
HostMax: 216.137.63.254

Finally I put together the following RewriteCond to stop the rules from redirecting requests coming from CloudFront:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^204\.246\.16([4567])\.\d{1,3}
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^54\.2(39|40)\.(12[89]|1[3-8][0-9]|19[01])\.\d{1,3}
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^204\.246\.(16[89]|17[01])\.\d{1,3}
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^204\.246\.1(7[4-9]|8[0-9]|9[01])\.\d{1,3}
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^54\.239\.(249|25[0-4])\.\d{1,3}
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^205\.251\.(19[2-9]|2[01][0-9]|22[0-3])\.\d{1,3}
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^216\.137\.(3[2-9]|[45][0-9]|6[0-3])\.\d{1,3}
```

However it does not seem to work and CloudFront requests are still redirected to the www version of the website.

Anyone, any suggestion?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add both "www" and non "www" hostnames as an origin for your Cloudfront distribution.  Get rid of the rewrite rules.  This should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
Do you mean something like:
    RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^(www\.|)204\.246\.16([4567])\.\d{1,3}

Could you clarify what rewrite rule we should get rid of?
Thank you very much!

Comment: @superuseroi All of them.  What you're trying to do isn't really a good idea.  That's why I recommended just specifying both hostnames as origins.

Comment: oh just got your comment.
Could you kindly provide an example for "specifying both hostnames as origins" ? And so much thank you for your suggestion

Comment: One more detail, if I understand correctly you suggest to remove all rewrite rules, but this is not possible, how would you go about non-www to www redirect? and many redirect rules are to stop common exploits, how would you take can of this?

Comment: I just wanted to follow up. I would appreciate if you could clarify your comment. Thank you again!

Comment: I have selected the answer as it did help me, however i feel it is partially unanswered as you did not return my comment, thank you anyway!